# Discord.py DM ALL doesn't send message to everyone

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So I have this code. It's supposed to DM everyone in server. It doesn't DM everyone, but only tries to DM the bot that's running on the code, which fails to do since it is impossible.

```py
@client.command()
async def adm(ctx, *, message):
    await ctx.message.delete()
    for user in ctx.guild.members:
        try:
            await user.send(message)
            print(f"Sent {user.name} a DM.")
        except:
            print(f"Couldn't DM {user.name}.")
    print("Sent all the server a DM.")
```

Comment: You need to enable members intents.

Comment: And how do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably happening because you didn't enable **Privileged Gateway intents** and your bot can't get all members. Enable `Server Members Intent` on the [Discord Developer](https://discord.com/developers/applications) site in the **Bot** section.

[image: discord site screenshot]

Then, add this to your code:

```py
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=intents)
```